# Какие значения имеет слово “фигачь”?

Tags: значения, сленг

Я это слово видел на разных форумах. Ну, в словаре сленга, не могу его найти.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Фигачь` - это 2 лицо единственного числа повелительного наклонения от глагола `фигачить`, этот глагол [есть даже в Викисловаре](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C):

> 1. *прост.* делать что-либо с усилием, старанием ◆ Вот ты это увидел, и вдруг у тебя сложилось и начинает в голове обрастать какими-то совершенно невероятными деталями, и ты садишься и начинаешь фигачить. (*Михаил Калужский, Сергей Минаев, «Сергей Минаев: я — неудавшийся лузер» // «Русский репортер», 2008 г.*)
> 2. *прост.* бить, колотить ◆ Потом берёшь кирпич вон там, в загашнике, фигачишь его гантелей в порошок. *Николай Рубан, «Тельняшка для киборга» // «Боевое искусство планеты», 2003 г.*

Answer (score 2):

Словом "фигачь" выделяют интенсивность действия . Само действие определяется из контекста .

Например: Вася смотри, вот они идут , фигачь их пулеметом. (Стреляй в них )
Да фигачь ее топором, все равно придется ломать. (Бей/руби топором)

Answer (score 0):

I would usually use it as a word to signify an action of making (completing) or filling something.

"Я *нафигачил* 10 листов теста" - "I *have done/completed* 10 page of a test"

Answer (score 0):

**Фигачить** - упорно работать над чем-либо:

- *Фигачил с утра до позднего вечера. Всю ночь над лабой фигачил.*

**(На)Фигачить** - что либо готовить:

- *Слыш, Маш, нафигачь каши!* (очень неформально)

**(За)фигачить** - забросить что-либо очень далеко:

- *Ну ты даешь, Олег! Так далеко зафигачил наш мяч - аж на соседнюю улицу.*

**(От)фигачить** - избить кого-то:

- *"Остальных предупреждаю - все будут схвачены и отфигачены", - сказал Абельцев на пленарном заседании Госдумы.*

Answer (score 0):

В слове "фигачить" имеет место использование некого абстрактного действия с упором на работу, создание чего-либо, обработку и прочее (батрачить, мастачить, колпачить), с заменой корня на корень "фиг" с грубым значением. Делается это для более абстрактного, неопределённого значения и, главное, для усиления эмоциональной окраски: "На фига до фига нафигачили? Расфигачивайте на фиг! - А на фига расфигачивать? Нафигачили - и фиг с ним!" Ещё более грубым и эмоционально усиленным будет замена на нецензурные, матерные корни. Хорошее описание русской обсценной лексики можно найти, например, [здесь](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82).

Answer (score -1):

Я бы сказал, что основное значение - "бросать", "бросать с высокой частотой", "бить с высокой частотой", "что-то делать, совершая поступательные движения с высокой частотой". Все остальные употребления мне кажутся не натуральными или производными. Например, "нафигачить много страниц текста" = "набросать много страниц текста", писать так быстро, что страницы падают в стопку.

Comment: Фигачить это просто эвфемизм для хуячить/хуярить — делать что-либо остервенело, в полную силу, с максимальной выкладкой.